# Alias library implicits in a package object

Tags: scala

Say I have:

```
import org.scalatest.ShouldMatchers._;
```

This brings a few `implicit` conversions into scope.

How can I alias them in a `package object` so that I can bring the implicits into scope with:

```
import code.ThePackageObject._;
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What do you need to do that can't be managed by creating a trait (or object or class) that mixes in ShouldMatchers (and whatever else you want for setting up your general test environment), then extending that?

Comment: Looks like  "implicit scope of a.A includes package object a" so don't put implicits in the package object unless you are sure. Otherwise what is the problem with regular implicit declarations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the `ShouldMatchers` object extends the `ShouldMatchers` trait (where the actual definition of the implicits are done). This is a common idiom that allows to simply mix the trait where you need it. So you can simply mix `ShouldMatchers` (the trait) in your package object:

```
package object ThePackageObject extends ShouldMatchers
```