# How to make a type alias available to multiple packages?

Tags: scala

I have some type aliases (and implicit conversions) in a package object that i would like to make available to other packages (within the same parent package).

Is it possible to do this with package objects or some other construct or do i need to create a global class with them (MyPredef._) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this may be your solution.. (im sorry I dont know how to link this as possible duplicate in Stackoverflow, if someone can do this to my answer please do)

[Alias library implicits in a package object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720777/alias-library-implicits-in-a-package-object)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried importing the package using the wildcard character?